# Python Turtle Draw Randomly Colored Circles

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to draw circles in 3 random colors.  But in this code, used to draw the circles, the output is without color:

```
import turtle

window=turtle.Screen()
tess= turtle. Turtle()

import random

def getColor():

    color=random.randint(1,3)
    if color==1:
        color="red"
    elif color==2:
        color=="yellow"
    elif color==3:
        color=="blue"
    return color
print (random.randint(1,3))

def drawFace (x,y):

    tess.penup()
    tess.goto(x+5,y+10)
    tess.circle(10)
    tess.goto(x+15,y+10)
    tess.circle(10)
    tess.pendown()
```

Comment: You are not using `getColor()`. At least not in this code. Also, you are generating two different numbers on two different randint() calls.

Answer (score 0):

In the `getColor()` function, you're not assigning to the `color` variable when it is yellow or blue - you're using double equal. Here's the fixed version:

```
def getColor():
    color=random.randint(1,3)
    if color==1:
        color="red"
    elif color==2:
        color="yellow"
    elif color==3:
        color="blue"
    return color
```

Secondly, you picked the pen up in the beginning of `drawFace()` and never put it down before finishing! Here's the fix:

```
def drawFace (x,y):
    tess.penup()
    tess.goto(x+5,y+10)
    tess.pendown()
    tess.circle(10)
    tess.penup()
    tess.goto(x+15,y+10)
    tess.pendown()
    tess.circle(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pick random numbers to index your colors, you can randomly pick one directly with `random.choice()`.  You need to call `GetColor()` and apply the color you've chosen via `tess.pencolor()`  We also tend to think of positioning circles based on their center but Python turtle doesn't so we need to (explicitly) adjust for that as you did (implicitly) in your code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random

RADIUS = 10

def getColor(turtle):
    choice = turtle.pencolor()

    while choice == turtle.pencolor():
        choice = random.choice(["red", "green", "blue"])

    return choice

def drawFace(turtle, x, y):
    turtle.pencolor(getColor(turtle))
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y - RADIUS)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(RADIUS)

tess = Turtle()

drawFace(tess, 5, 0)

drawFace(tess, 15, 0)

screen = Screen()

screen.exitonclick()
```